# Django-Filter | Looping over form fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I am using `django-filter` which works as intended. I am however trying to loop over the form fields but the [standard django attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) aren't working. The only one that does is `{{ form.id_for_label }}`. Am I missing something?

My template code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {% for form in forms.form.product_colours %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="product_colours" id="{{ form.id_for_label }}" value="{{ form.value }}">
        <label for="{{ form.id_for_label }}">{{ form.label }}</label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The reason I don't want to simply use `{{ form }}` is because it loads the `<label>` before the `<input>` whereas I'd need it to work viceversa to fit into my styling. I would prefer not to have to change the styling.

In case they are needed, here are my (simplified) `models`, `FilterSet` and my `view`:

**Model**:

```
class ProductColour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    colour_hex = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="#FFF")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(Page):
    # My product fields
    product_colours = ParentalManyToManyField('products.ProductColour', blank=True)
```

**FilterSet**:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product_colours = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(name="product_colours", 
        label="Product Colour", 
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
        queryset=ProductColour.objects.all(), 
        conjoined=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_colours']
```

**View**:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(Page, self).get_context(request)

    all_products = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.live()).qs
    forms = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.live())

    paginator = Paginator(all_products, 9) # Show 9 resources per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context['forms'] = forms
    context['products'] = products

    return context
```

In case you are wondering what the `ParentalManyToManyField` is, it's a [Wagtail CMS](http://www.wagtail.io) class.

Comment: can you please add model for products. but try this first and let me know
      
       {% for x,y in form.fields.instruments.choices %}
          <option value="{{ x }}">{{ y }}</option>
      {% endfor %}

Comment: @bhattravii OK I have updated the OP. Nope didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: Put  {% for check in form %} {% endfor %}  after{% for form in forms.form.product_colours %}  and check what fields you are getting there

Comment: Hmmm... Strange, I'm getting a `'BoundWidget' object is not iterable` error. @Vicmathur

Comment: check {{ forms.form.product_colours|length }} or {{ forms.form.product_colours.count }}

Comment: @Vicmathur - Bingo! I googled BoundWidget and looked through the Django docs - I tried adding the `data` parameter and it works! So instead of `form.value` it's `form.data.value`. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

OK so I have found the solution - as user @Vicmathur suggested in the comments above I tried adding `{% for check in form %}{% endfor %}` and it threw up a `'BoundWidget' object is not iterable` error.

So I googled `BoundWidget` and found the [related Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/boundfield/).

Instead of trying to access the data through, for example, `{{ form.value }}`, I need to specify`{{ form.data.value }}`